# Employee share purchase plans,exit options, IRS

Tags: united-states, taxes, espp

I am investigating the options for what to do with an Employee Share Purchase plan upon retirement that do not result in having to pay a big tax to IRS. I understand that I will have a taxable event if I take constructive receipt of the shares but I believe I can also transfer them to a 401k or some other type of arms length plan.....  Looking for some detailed information on choices.

Comment: To my understanding ESPP exist outside of retirement plans. So there isn't a way to avoid the taxable event. If you have access to your plan documentation, you should quote relevant parts, or describe your ESPP in more detail.

Comment: How are you defining "big tax"? Have you already bought shares and just wanting to avoid paying tax on selling them? The only thing you'd pay tax on is the _gain_ from the time you bought them - the discount you received when buying them should have been taxed as income at that time.

Answer (score 1):

ESPP are typically bought at a discount, the discount is taxed as ordinary income. The remaining gains are taxed as long term cap gains when held for over 2 years. Depending on your income during retirement, that can be 0%, up to 15% maximum. That’s not too bad.

Comment: This answer is very incomplete. Shares are taxed as long term capital gains after 1 year, not 2. Two years are the point where sale becomes a qualifying disposition as opposed to a disqualifying disposition (which this answer does not attempt to distinguish between). You also don't mention when the 2 years start (hint: not when the shares are purchased)

Comment: If you post a complete, accurate answer, I’d gladly delete mine. I retired in 2012, and have clearly forgotten the full details of ESPP.